# Parsing ansible playbook output

Tags: parsing, ansible

My playbook is as follows

---

```
  - name: Juniper SRX Compliance checks
    hosts: juniper
    gather_facts: false
    tasks:
    - name: Syslog server check
      junos_config:
         src: /home/gefelas/ansible_junos/files/syslog_config.txt
      diff: true
      register: junos_output
    - debug:
        msg: Syslog server check - This check has failed with the following output({{ junos_output.diff.prepared }})
       when: junos_output.changed
    - debug:
        msg: Syslog server check - This check has passed with the following output({{ junos_output.diff.prepared }})
      when: not junos_output.changed
```

It produce the output ( using stdout_callback = community.general.yaml in the ansible.cfg )

```
msg: |-
 Syslog server check - This check has failed with the following output([edit system syslog host 192.168.100.70]
+     interactive-commands any;
[edit system syslog host 192.168.100.70]
+    facility-override local1;
+    log-prefix firewall;
+    source-address 172.16.203.121;
+    explicit-priority;
[edit system syslog]
+    file messages {
+        any critical;
+        authorization info;
+    }
+    file default-log-messages {
+        structured-data;
+    }
+    file sessions {
+        user info;
+    }
+    file interactive-commands {
+        interactive-commands error;
+    })
```

What regex module would be appropraite to produce the following output

```
msg: |-
   Syslog server check - This check has failed with the following output

    set system syslog archive size 300000
    set system syslog archive files 3
    set system syslog archive world-readable
    set system syslog user * any emergency
    set system syslog host 192.168.100.70 any any
    set system syslog host 192.168.100.70 interactive-commands any
    set system syslog host 192.168.100.70 facility-override local1
    set system syslog host 192.168.100.70 log-prefix firewall
    set system syslog host 192.168.100.70 source-address "172.16.203.121"
    set system syslog host 192.168.100.70 explicit-priority
    set system syslog file messages any critical
    set system syslog file messages authorization info
    set system syslog file default-log-messages structured-data
    set system syslog file sessions user info
    set system syslog file interactive-commands interactive-commands error
```

Would adding something resembling this to the playbook make any difference ?

```
  - set_fact:  
     junos_output: |  
      {{ junos_output |  
      map('regex_replace','.*\\s+( )\\s+.*','\\g<ip>') |   
  list }}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain better what you want to do and why, because I think trying to parse stdout from ansible is really a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I give you my best trick for printing 'set' stuff for routers in a plaintext in Ansible. It's dirty and it breaks abstractions, but it so convenient, that I still love it.

```
- name: Print configuration
  delegate_to: localhost
  shell: "echo '{{ srx_config|join(cr) }}' > /dev/tty"
  when: ansible_verbosity > 0
  changed_when: false
  vars:
    cr: '{{ "\n" }}'
```

The main trick here is the use of `/dev/tty` for output. If you run playbook with -v option you get all lines from srx_config in plantext on screen without quotes, etc. All you have to do to debug it, is to log into console and paste them info 'configure' mode.

Comment: How can I fit this all under the Juniper SRX Compliance checks task ?

Comment: I'm not really understand your concerns. If you need to fit a task under other task you write a new task under existing one. Tasklist is a list.